# How to read and store all the contacts to a list from contacts database?

Tags: android, android-contacts, sqliteopenhelper

I m trying to read the contacts from the contacts table and store all of them into a list variable..but not able to make out why it doesnt seem to work..gets a force close on execution.the contacts are needed to be send over a json object to a web server.

```
      private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";



// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    List<contact> l=new ArrayList<contact>();
    String query="SELECT * FROM"+ TABLE_CONTACTS;

     DBHelper help= new DBHelper(getBaseContext()); 
    SQLiteDatabase db=help.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            contact contact = new contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            Toast.makeText(this,contact.name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             l.add(contact);
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

and manifest file has 2 permissions

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

and DBHelper class which is used to extend sqlitopenhelper to getWritableDatabase..

```
    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

   // Contacts table name
   private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
DBHelper(Context context) { 
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null,1); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

}

Comment: Are your trying to use Contacts from phone..?

Comment: @ValayPatel ..Yes ,,,from predefined contact table in the android phone

Comment: Let me know that below link works or not... Otherwise I can write a small code and send that to you.

Comment: @ValayPatel ...after some digging it seems i was wrong with the table name....sql error....does there exist any other table for contacts...and i appreciate your time for this...if u have the code or if it takes very less time for u then mail me..shri16@gmail.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void getDetails(){
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
    Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    names.moveToFirst();
    do {
       String name   = names.getString(indexName);
       Log.e("Name new:", name);
       String number = names.getString(indexNumber);
       Log.e("Number new:","::"+number);
    } while (names.moveToNext());
}
```

use the above code to get a list of name and numbers from contacts database.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking..

[Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) **Depricated**

[ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html)